# hiding some elements to display in different screen sizes using bootstrap d- is not working for me.Please explain why

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
                <a href="index.html" class="pull-left d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
                    <div id="logo-img" alt="image"></div>
                </a>
```

i wanted an img to display only on >=large screens but the image is showing on every screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work just fine the way it is, displaying the element in screens between 992px and 1200px.

Make sure your bootstrap's css files are being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@media screen only min-width(somepixel){display:none;}